# NSScrollView one line at a time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview

I'm currently making a simple text editing program with Cocoa and Objective-C and I'm trying to make it scroll one line at a time with any type of scrolling.

I can make it scroll only one line by setting the `setLineScroll` parameter to the current line height for the NSScrollView. This only controls it when you press the arrows on the scroll bar. I would like to force it to only scroll one line at a time with both the arrows and the scroll wheel/track pad gestures.

If I subclass NSScrollView can I control this with the moveUp and moveDown methods for NSScrollView?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could override

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

, calculate the line height like you did for the setLineScroll method and scroll manually to the new scroll position.

You would probably need something like this

```
NSPoint currentPoint=[[scrollView contentView] bounds].origin;
currentPoint.y += _lineHeight
[[scrollView documentView] scrollPoint:currentPoint];
```

The sign will depend on the direction of the move.